# Download xlsx file via saveAs by POST

Tags: angularjs, excel, post, filesaver.js

Hello i am have function for download file excel (.xlsx):

```
 getXls(params) {
    return this.$http.post('/api/xls', params, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'responseType': 'blob'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers("content-type") });
            saveAs(blob, response.headers('content-disposition').split('=')[1])
    })
```

But when open downloaded excel file see this:
[image]
When download via Postman all content in file right;

Comment: Post your response headers

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200  
Server:nginx/1.13.5
Date:Thu, 09 Nov 2017 16:05:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Length: 5632
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=45
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Report.xlsx